# Adding Firebase reduces app overall speed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have built an app that searches for books using Google Books API. Its' functionality stands in a search bar that queries for some particular books and them displays them in a Listview.
I then decided to add Firebase as a cloud backend for my app.

**Note:** Before adding Firebase my app took around 1 sec to retrieve information and display searched books in the ListView (for first search) and approx. 500ms to any after searches.

After implementing Firebase(added sign up and log in activities and xmls that lead to the main activity that actually searches for books) I started to experience unpleasant waiting time.

From couple of seconds for a simple log-in to **around 5 seconds for first query and display (of books) and 4 seconds for any after queries and displays of books (that is around 5 times slower comparing to older version of the app without Firebase).**

I am posting the App-level Build.gradle file for info purposes:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.booktrade_v10"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Do you guys have any ideas why my app started being so slow?

*Any help is appreciated.*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited it so you can see this post as a question

Comment: FYI the version of Firebase SDKs you're using are about a year old.  Try 11.0.2 which is current today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After implementing Firebase (added sign up and log in activities

These operations require that the Firebase SDK connects to its servers, validates the user account, and creates a token. This takes time.

Comment: This would explain the log-in delay. But it doesn't explain the huge delay I get from quering and displaying data in a ListView ( which is independent from Firebase as I am not storing any data)

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to say anything conclusive. This would include the data, the rules, the code - for each the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem. Only with that can we have a reasonable chance of seeing what you're doing and having an idea of what's going on.